# Inverse Laplacian

Tags: cosmology, operators, tensor-calculus, differentiation, cosmological-inflation

I have seen the following operator somewhere in a paper on cosmology
$$
\frac{\partial_i \partial_j}{\nabla^2} - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij}.
$$
What is the definition of the inverse Laplacian? What is meant by this misleading notation? Is this the inverse Laplacian? If yes, what is then $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's write an arbitrary function $f:\,\Bbb R^3\mapsto\Bbb R$ as a Fourier transform:$$f(\vec{r})=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\Bbb R^3}\tilde{f}(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k},\,f(\vec{k}):=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\Bbb R^3}f(\vec{r})e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{r}.$$(I've restricted to a $3$-dimensional space because I'm confident that's why $\frac13$ comes up in the expression you encountered.) The most obvious definition of $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}f$ is$$\frac{1}{\nabla^2}f:=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac{\tilde{f}(\vec{k})}{-k^2}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}=(2\pi)^{-3}\int_{(\Bbb R^3)^2}\frac{f(\vec{R})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{R})}}{-k^2}d^3\vec{k}d^3\vec{R}.$$This coincides with @Vincent's definition of $(\nabla^2)^{-1}$ provided$$(2\pi)^{-3}\int_{\Bbb R^3}\frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{z}}}{k^2+m^2}d^3\vec{k}=\frac{e^{-mz}}{4\pi z}$$is taken as $m\to0^+$ (strictly speaking, this is a distributional limit). By Fourier inversion, this conjecture is equivalent to$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\frac{e^{-mz-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{z}}d^3\vec{z}}{4\pi z}=\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}.$$Indeed, spherical polars rewrite the LHS as$$\begin{align}\frac12\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\int_0^\infty ze^{-(m+ik\cos\theta)z}dz&=\frac12\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\theta}{(m+ik\cos\theta)^2}d\theta\\&=\frac{1}{2ik}\left[\frac{1}{m+ik\cos\theta}\right]_0^\pi\\&=\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}.\end{align}$$This is quite a complicated manipulation, so it pays to use dimensional analysis as a power-counting sanity check.

Answer (score 11):

Every Laplacian can be inverted using its [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function). If we have
$$\nabla^2V = \rho$$
the inverse is simply
$$V(x) = \left(\nabla^2\right)^{-1} (\rho) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\rho(x')}{|x-x'|} \text{d}^3x'$$
and that's what's meant by $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}$, at least in the places where I've seen it.

Comment: If we define $\Delta:=\nabla^2$, then what is $\Delta^{-1}$? I would say this is what you have defined and not $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @Immanuel See the last line in my answer above. In all the papers I've seen, $\frac{1}{\nabla^2}$ means $\Delta^{-1}$.

Comment: But this is a ridiculous notation! Because $\Delta^{-1}$ for me means the inverse operator  of $\Delta$, as you defined it. Inverse in the sense of operator and not $\frac{1}{\text{something}}$.

Comment: I mean you are probably right. But I found this notation very misleading. BTW, does your definition coincide with J.G.'s answer?

Comment: @Immanuel Well $\sin^2 x$ does not mean $\sin(\sin(x))$ either

Comment: No! It is square function. You define a function $f$ and then $f^2:=f \cdot f$ does make sense. Now set $f=\sin$.

Comment: @Immanuel I won't inveigh on the "should operators' inverses be denoted as reciprocals?" debate, but you might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) an interesting context where notational questions like that are important.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! It looks interesting. I will have a look at that. I asked another stupid question: are both of your answers equivalent?

Comment: @Immanuel I'm working on an edit to show they are.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition unfortunately function composition can also use power notation in general, though there are listed ways to avoid this ambiguity, and physicists tend to avoid using it for good reason. This is the main reason I call the inverse trig functions by their longer names (arctangent, arccosine, arcsin...etc.)